# PHP Array to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to build a JSON object from a mysql query. The JSON structure that I'm striving for should look like this:

```
   {
        "a": [
            {
                "user": "alb",
                "time": "2011-09-12 05:56:36"
            },
            {
                "user": "arg",
                "time": "2011-09-12 05:56:36"
            }
             ]
        "b": [
            {
                "user": "blah",
                "time": "2011-09-12 05:56:36"
            },
            {
                "user": "bleh",
                "time": "2011-09-12 05:56:36"
            }
             ]
}
```

However, my code always returns a JSON object wrapped in an array like so:

```
[
       {
            "a": [
                {
                    "user": "alb",
                    "time": "2011-09-12 05:56:36"
                },
                {
                    "user": "arg",
                    "time": "2011-09-12 05:56:36"
                }
                 ]
            "b": [
                {
                    "user": "blah",
                    "time": "2011-09-12 05:56:36"
                },
                {
                    "user": "bleh",
                    "time": "2011-09-12 05:56:36"
                }
                 ]
    }
]
```

Here is the php code I'm using:

```
<?php
$json_data = array();
foreach($blogs as $blog)
{
    $sql    = "SELECT * from users";
    $query  = mysql_query($sql);
    $ablog   = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $json_element = array(
        "user"=> $row[username] ,
        "time"=> $row[time]
        );
        array_push($ablog,$json_element);
    }
    $eblog = array($blog => $ablog);
    array_push($json_data,$eblog);

}
$json_output = json_encode($json_data);
print $json_output;
?>
```

I was wondering: Why am I getting a JSON object wrapped in an array? What am I doing incorrectly in the code above?

Thank you.

Comment: Both json is invalid you need to add comma before **"b":**

Comment: You should post the *actual* output of your program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following two lines are creating one-element associative arrays and appending the one-element array to your larger `$json_data` array:

```
$eblog = array($blog => $ablog);
array_push($json_data,$eblog);
```

Instead, just add a new key/value pair to your original array:

```
$json_data[$blog] = $ablog;
```